# NULL value self comparison in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I am always puzzled regarding some mysterious t-sql behavior, like the following

```
-- Create table t and insert values.  
use tempdb
CREATE TABLE dbo.t (a INT NULL);  
-- insert 3 values
INSERT INTO dbo.t values (NULL),(0),(1);  
GO  
set ansi_nulls off -- purposely turn off, so we can allow NULL comparison, such as null = null
go
-- expect 3 rows returned but only 2 returned (without null value row)
select * from dbo.t where a = a
```

This is not about how to retrieve all rows in a table and also not about avoiding use of ANSI_NULLS.

I just want to solicit some insights why t-sql behaves like this.

Answer (score 13):

This is a surprising behaviour but from MSDN page, [`SET ANSI_NULLS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx), we can at least know that is the expected behaviour. One more reason to never use `ANSI_NULLS OFF`:

> `SET ANSI_NULLS` affects a comparison only if one of the operands of the comparison is either a variable that is `NULL` or a literal  `NULL`. **If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison.**

Answer (score 8):

While it may not be crystal clear from the msdn documentation, I believe you will find the following true

"SET ANSI_NULLS ON affects a comparison only if one of the operands of the comparison is either a variable that is NULL or a literal NULL. If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison."

See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866714/how-does-ansi-nulls-work-in-tsql

Comment: Thanks Scott and ypercube, both your answers are to the points for this behavior, so I upvote both your answers.

Comment: Ypercube was first:)

Answer (score 4):

Robert Sheldon in the following post from 2015 discusses NULL behaviors and why they sometimes (but not always) fail

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/

He describes 13 NULL failures that a programmer can easily trip over.

**Failure #1: Not knowing what NULL means**

Explanation: *NULL is a non-value, a nonexistent value. It is not zero. It is not an empty string. A value cannot equal NULL. **No two NULL values are equal**.*

That is the basic problem, but be sure to read about the other failures.

Yes, earlier versions (pre-SQL Server 7 I believe) behaved differently, more like what you are wanting.

However, if you search for the issue on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange you will find many long threads discussing the issues.

Comment: I once read the linked post from Robert Sheldon, but it does not (IMHO) have any theory or evidence that explain the behavior of my example.

Comment: *"No two NULL values are equal."* OK but even the people who know that would expect the opposite when ansi nulls is set to off. Especially because `WHERE NULL = NULL` yields true when the setting is of.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the discussion, the [SQL92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) standard's definition of NULL can be interpreted ambiguously.  Here's a [good summary of NULL handling and interpretation](https://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html) from various DBMSes courtesy of sqlite.org.

**DISCLOSURE**:  I kinda remember reading about SQL92's "ambiguity" from an older version (like 6-8 years ago) of the sqlite.org page linked above, but that page has been updated since.

RLF's answer above has a good quote, but if I disagree with Robert Sheldon it's only because I consider "something that does not exist" (i.e. a *NULL*) to be philosophically and English-language-semantically equivalent to "something *else* that does not exist".  If I am to understand Sheldon's logic, then one could declare the definition of NULL is **also** NULL.  (If it doesn't exist, then how can we define it?  Creepy, huh?)

I see a variation of [Russell's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) brewing (*and* a headache). :-\

But again, this is a discussion on [English language semantics](https://english.stackexchange.com/) (*NOT* SQL) and the philosophy debate belongs [over here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/). :-)

Comment: P.S. I'm new here to this SE community; if this has been discussed _ad nauseum_ before, then I apologize.

Comment: Where exactly is the ambiguity in the standard?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: I believe the ambiguity lay in the attempt to "fit" a [3VL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) into a Boolean.  Table joins with [NULL comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Challenges) could be interpreted in several different ways.

Comment: I would agree about inconsistency but not about ambiguity.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Fair enough... I was only quoting what an older version of the sqlite.org page I linked above said ("SQL92 is ambiguous with regards to NULL handling and interpretation" or something very similar).  But I don't mean to argue.  Perhaps the sqlite.org page was itself misleading and/or all-out incorrect.  Which likely explains why it was updated.